# Django QuerySet evaluation on .all()

Tags: django

I am trying to find out if it is *safe* to do the following:

```
items = MyModel.objects.filter(q)
if items:
    list(items)
```

I know that the `QuerySet` is being evaluated in the `if` statement, checking if the database returns an empty set. But I want to know if the value of that evaluation is reused when doing `list(items)`. Is the `QuerySet` being evaluated here too, or is it using the previously evaluated one?

I know I could just do the following:

```
items = MyModel.objects.filter(q).all()
if items:
    list(items)
```

And this would result in one evaluation, but I am just trying to find out the behavior the first variation has. I have gone throught these pieces of doc ([1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/) [2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)) but couldn't really find a straight answer to this matter.

Comment: I think there is no difference between `MyModel.objects.filter(q)` and `MyModel.objects.filter(q).all()`.

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: @albar huh, I always thought `.all()` forced the evaluation.

Comment: .all(): "Returns a copy of the current QuerySet (or QuerySet subclass). This can be useful in situations where you might want to pass in either a model manager or a QuerySet and do further filtering on the result. After calling all() on either object, you’ll definitely have a QuerySet to work with."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Both will not execute twice (internally `.filter()`, `.all()` and `.filter().all()` are same). You can check it in django `shell` itself

```
from django.db import connection
print connection.queries

items = MyModel.objects.filter(q).all() #or MyModel.objects.filter(q)
if items:
    list(items)

print connection.queries
```

**Then here is the magic of `.all()`**

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.all() #no db hit, hit=0
print list(queryset)             #db hit,    hit=1
print list(queryset)             #no db hit, hit=1
print list(queryset.all())       #db hit,    hit=2
print list(queryset.all())       #db hit,    hit=3
```

That means `.all()` on an evaluated queryset will force db hit.

> When a QuerySet is evaluated, it typically caches its results. If the data in the database might have changed since a QuerySet was evaluated, you can get updated results for the same query by calling all() on a previously evaluated QuerySet

Comment: I am asking if both are going to be executed twice in the first case, not the second. I explicitly said in my original post that I know the query would be executed only once in the second case. I am asking about the first.

Comment: Here what you mean by execution ?. If it means db hit, it will only one time.Also both your case is same behind the scenes.`.all()` at end of `filter()` will not make any difference.

Comment: Oh, I thought `.all()` would force the evaluation. Can you refer to docs or anything at all that backs that the db will only be hit once?

Answer (score 2):

It will reuse it's cache, because when you do

```
if items:
```

It will call `__bool__` method

```
def __bool__(self):
    self._fetch_all()
    return bool(self._result_cache)
```

So as you see inside `__bool__` it does call `_fetch_all`. Which caches data

```
def _fetch_all(self):
    if self._result_cache is None:
        self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
    if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
        self._prefetch_related_objects()
```

Comment: Can you back your statement that the db is hit twice instead of once with some reference?

Comment: @dabadaba fixed. It will reuse cache

Comment: [There is no `__bool__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9269dec05efae5deb89912a5b9a98ae75acdfff9/django/db/models/query.py#L245)? (Both call `_fetch_all()`, so it won't really make a difference, but `__bool__` is defined.)

Answer (score 1):

For better perfomance do:

```
items = MyModel.objects.filter(q)  # no evaluation
if items.exists():  # evaluates, hits db
    # do stuff here  # further actions evaluates, hits db
```

Comment: That hits the db twice. The whole point of my question is taking advantage of the evaluation in the `if` statement so it can be reused later.

Comment: My bad. @itzmeontv is right. With your way, there is only one db hit (the one in the `if`). Then the `list(items)` does not hit db again.